# Loop and TAD calling from HiC reads using HOMER

Tags: hi-c

I have HiC reads from an HiC experiment and I am using HOMER to call loops and TADs. The numbers I am getting are like:

Total TADs: 5024; Total Loops : 254

As multiple loops are expected in a TAD so numbers of loops should be higher than the number of TADs. That's why I am not sure how to justify the numbers I am getting.

I made sure I am not doing any mistake in the HOMER pipeline of loop/TAD calling and I followed all the steps in the tutorial here: http://homer.ucsd.edu/homer/interactions2/index.html Unfortunately I don't have any other loop calling program installed right now and HOMER is easy to install and run.

If someone working with HiC data analysis and TAD/loop calling from HiC reads can please comment on this?

Thanks

Following is the set of commands I used (based on HOMER tutorial here http://homer.ucsd.edu/homer/interactions2/index.html) to get loop/TAD calls from HiC reads.
**#Trimming/processing of HiC fastq files:**

homerTools trim -3 GATC -mis 0 -matchStart 20 -min 20 Hu_concat_1.fastq

homerTools trim -3 GATC -mis 0 -matchStart 20 -min 20 Hu_concat_2.fastq

**#Aligning the two paired-end fastq files to get sam:**

bowtie2 -p 20 -x hg38.fa -U Hu_concat_1.fastq.trimmed > Hu_concat_1.sam

bowtie2 -p 20 -x hg38.fa -U Hu_concat_2.fastq.trimmed > Hu_concat_2.sam

**#Making tag directory (the HOMER makeTagDirectory program is used to process the alignment file into a HOMER-style tag directory which is used for subsequent analysis steps)**

makeTagDirectory Hu_Hic_TagDir/ Hu_concat_1.sam,Hu_concat_2.sam -tbp 1

**#Calling loops and TADs**

findTADsAndLoops.pl find Hu_Hic_TagDir/ -cpu 10 -res 10000 -window 15000 -genome hg38.fa

The whole process ran smoothly without errors. It is just that in the output, the number of loops I am getting are far fewer than no. of TADs (Total TADs: 5024; Total Loops : 254) which I think is not biologically correct. If someone using HOMER for calling loops and TADs from HiC reads can justify this output, that would be really helpful.